# Validating a JOptionPane ConfirmDialog

Tags: java

I use this code to make sure that the user didn't leave the combo box empty before pressing OK

```
            int option=-1;
            while(cboFruits.getSelectedItem() == null){
             option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Fruits", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
             if (!(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION))                 
                 break; 
             if(cboFruits.getSelectedItem() == null)             
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a fruit");             
            }
```

Is there a better alternative to this that doesn't involve creating my own Dialog? The combo box gets filled with data when another combobox changes its value, so putting a value by default is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems fine. But some minor improvements are possible:

- It's unnatural to write `!(x == y)`, the more natural way is `x != y`
- I'm wondering if `option` is needed outside the loop are all. If not, then you should declare and initialize it inside the loop.
- in every iteration, you check `cboFruits.getSelectedItem()== null` twice: once after the use clicked OK, and then again in the loop condition. It would be better to rearrange this code in a way that the condition is checked once per iteration.
- It's recommended to use braces always, even with single line `if` statements

Comment: Changed my code a bit to add everything you said (see edited code if curious). I didn't know brackets were recommended, I usually never put them on single line statements.

Comment: [this kind of thing](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) can happen when you don't put always and with a little bad luck and oversight